# Center text android button

Tags: android, gravity

My question is very simple.
How do I center the text on a button in android?
I tried to set padding to 0, gravity to center but the result when i run it still that the text is horizontal centred but not vertical. The text is a bit shifted to the bottom.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_button_different"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:height="30dp"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:text="@string/equals"
    android:textColor="@drawable/layout_button_different"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:width="70dp" />
```

My be also relevant:
In activity I do this:

```
btnEquals.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.up2), null, null);
btnEquals.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
btnEquals.setTextSize(15);
```

This works but after this I set this:

```
btnEquals.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
btnEquals.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Result is a bad vertical alignment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your existing layout cannot hope to center the text due to the sizes you have selected. You've set the button height to `30dp` and your textSize is `50dp`, and for whatever reason, Android is unable to deal with that and center the text. If you make your button larger or your text smaller you'll see that the centering works.

Comment: if Height is 30dp then what is the use of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: @hotveryspicy -- put the button layout into an xml and load it up, and you'll see that the `wrap_content` appears to not care about the spill of the text in this case. I don't know why that happens, but it's what happens (at least when viewed through the Eclipse visual display of the layout; I didn't put it on a device).

Comment: Thanks but deleting android:layout_height or android:layout_width resolves in a RuntimeException.

Comment: @dieters -- no one has suggested you delete either of those; they are required by Android. android:textSize="50dp" is the issue -- especially if you're changing it to 15 in code; either get rid of it or just set it to 15 in the layout.

Comment: ahah i had the exact problem :) you saved me weekend :)

Comment: android:gravity vs android:layout_gravity

android:gravity is used to specify the gravity of the content of the view. android:layout_gravity is an attribution the child can supply to its parent, to specify the gravity the view within its parents.

Answer (score 51):

It's easy peasy, you can put this:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think you can simplify it into a single line android:textAlignment="center".

Comment: Thanks @Alex for your answer.

Comment: Not work .......

Comment: @reza_khalafi, Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

There are three systems to consider. The xml layout designer, the simulator, and real phone. The text in the button if you specify gravity="center" will look like this.
In xml layout designer it will look like the leftmost letter is in the center of the button but the rest of the letters are to the right. (looks incorrect)
In simulator, the text shows well in the center. (correct)
In phone, the text shows well in the center.  (correct)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I spent 15 minutes wondering what I was doing wrong and it turns out it just 'looks' incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this line to your Button in layout xml code:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use negative numbers in setPadding. This may help if your font is large and your button is small. Try also setting the top or bottom to a more negative number if it's still off center.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set **layout_height** to **wrap_content** and vary the **padding** attribute for whatever value you want

Answer (score -2):

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/AnswerE"
                style="@style/defaultbuttonstyle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="AnswerCheck"
                android:text=" E "
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This worked for me

Comment: you did not made it clear what attribute will help centering the content of the button, in the provided question content is "text" and the attribute 
android:gravity="center" help you center the content.