# Android button text not aligned properly

Tags: java, android

I have a button and even though the text is centered on the layout preview, when I run the application it slides down. Any idea of what may be happening.

**Button XML**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/increment_setup_activity"
    android:layout_width="131dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:background="@drawable/settings_panel"
    android:text="+"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/soft_color"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/
```

**Android Studio Layout Preview**

[image: Android studio layout preview]

**Running on my phone**

[image: Mobile output]

Comment: did the searching for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10978706/4944007

Comment: try reducing the font size and see if it is centered

Comment: This is indeed the problem, I saw this post and I did alter the text before posting this question but it was still not centered. After finding the link to the post again - this time by you -  I decided to make a more extreme reduction and it works fine. I am not sure if I should flag my question or leave it here. Nevertheless a big thanks and an upvote to you.

Comment: caiomcg I'll add an answer please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a larger font size center align text  (by default on a button) does not work try reducing the font size more info [visit this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978550/center-text-android-button/10978706#10978706)

Answer (score -1):

**add it's:**

```
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"  
                  android:gravity="center"
                  >
```

**add your component here and button**

```
</LinearLayout>
```